# React native export issue

Tags: react-native, expo

i have build an ReactNative application with Expo i want render function component inside class component and face issue with export while i very sure i did include export the component

the error show :

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of Register

the component i want to render

```
DateModal.js




import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
import DatePicker from '../../utils/calendar/containers/datepicker/datepicker';
import { Text, TextInput } from '../core';

export default function DateModal(){
  
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>waffffa</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: How does your import look in your Resister component? It should be `import DateModal from ...` not `import { DateModal } from ...`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-hawking-nu05n2

Comment: import { Text, TextInput } from '../core'; you have to look into it, you imported Text and TextInput from core file make sure you have these components in core file or you can import it from react-native. @wafa.A

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will resolve your problem but you can try to export default after the function , and also try to import Text and TextInput from react-native

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView, Text, TextInput
} from 'react-native';

function DateModal(){
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>waffffa</Text>
            <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        value={12}
        placeholder="useless placeholder"
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
        </View>
        
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    input: {
      height: 40,
      margin: 12,
      borderWidth: 1,
      padding: 10,
    },
  });

export default DateModal;
```

And in your main js

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import DateModal from './components/DateModal';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <DateModal />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: it show same error , can i render functional competent inside class competent ?

Comment: Yes you can render functional component into a class, try to delete all of your import in your DateModal.js except for ` import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView, Text, TextInput
} from 'react-native';
`